# How to center QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I'm trying to center my QDialog.

Here's a code I used:

```
QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
int x = (screenGeometry.width() - this->width()) / 2;
int y = (screenGeometry.height() - this->height()) / 2;
this->move(x, y);
```

But I didn't get my dialog at an appropriate posistion. When I printed values of a dialog's width and height I noticed that they were much smaller than a real ones. To check if something was working in a wrong way I changed it's geometry:

```
this->setGeometry(100,100,this->width(),this->height());
```

And my dialog shrank...

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: It would be great if you could post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those of us who have Qt installed can just paste and start helping immediately.

Comment: Unless you are setting a fixed size to your dialog, the size of the dialog is not calculated until it is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
QRect windowRect = rect();
```

First get a copy of your own window rect.

```
windowRect.moveCenter(screenGeometry.center());
```

Move the copy to the center of the screen's rect.

```
move(windowRect.topLeft());
```

Perform the actual move: set your windows top left point to the calculated top left point. No resize is necessary.